# Are we missing anything to end the Private Beta?

Tags: discussion, beta

We are about a week into Private Beta, and seem to be doing great.  Is there anything in particular we need to focus on addressing to get ready for public Beta?

Comment: Yes this http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/questions/376/poor-quality-advice-in-answers-and-comments

Comment: If you have concerns about answers, flag them.  The SE moderators can address them, until we have our own.

Comment: James se doesn't really work like that. Mods won't just delete posts. I'll have to go to sleep soon, but can go into more tomorrow, if needed.

Comment: We are now out of private beta.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-completed]? :-)

Answer (score 14):

*Just a brief administrative note:*

We typically do our private beta evaluation just about now, but the entire Community Team is in New York this week for a Summit meeting. The site seems to be doing well overall, but the evaluations and related activities are being deferred until next week when we return.

Answer (score 7):

You want something to do?  Here you go.

We don't have so many questions that you'd get overwhelmed doing this...

1. sort all questions by activity
2. list 50 per page
3. go to the least active question
4. review the question

   - tactical edit for proper grammar / sentence structure
   - flag invalid comments for review (obsolesence)
   - if you think it deserves it, vote (up/down) the post
5. for each answer

   - tactical edit for proper grammar / sentence structure
   - flag invalid comments for review (obsolesence)
   - if you think it deserves it, vote (up/down) the post
6. go to the next question in your queue and repeat till you're bored.

If you want to "gameify" it, think of it as a way to keep you on track for your Electorate, Civic Duty and Copy Editor badges.

Answer (score 3):

Given the response answer from Robert Cartaino, I think that JoshDM has a [great plan](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374/are-we-missing-anything-to-end-the-private-beta/381#381).

This gives another week of just our small group.  Our stats on [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44686/pets) look good, and as long as we keep adding a couple of questions and answers we should be fine there.

One of the things I noticed in the Beta at [Space](https://space.stackexchange.com/) is the importance of really good questions (high interest) for drawing in new visitors. If your not familiar with "Hot Questions" take a look there can be a huge impact to the site for questions that get there (plus you get badges).

[image]

If you have any really good questions, or a medium question that could be good, take this time to make it better, post it a week or so after we enter public beta.